# failed passed data with protocol

Tags: swift, delegates, swift-protocols

Hi I have a problem passing data with my custom `delegate`, please help everyone this is my code

```
protocol VideoCellDelegate {
    func didSaveFavorite(for cell: SearchVideoCell)
}
```

and I put my `delegate` inside `SearchVideoCell`

```
class SearchVideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var delegate: VideoCellDelegate?
```

and this is my function inside `SearchVideoCell`

```
@objc func handleFavorite() {
    print("Handling favorite")
    delegate?.didSaveFavorite(for: self)
}
```

than I tried passed in in `SearchVideoController`

```
class SearchVideoController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, VideoCellDelegate
```

than I called the `delegate` but it's not working, it's only print `Handling Favorite` not `saving video to favorite`

```
func didSaveFavorite(for cell: SearchVideoCell) {
    print("saving video to favorite")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't set the controller as the delegate object when you made the cell.

//In your controller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchVideoCell
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I forgot to assign my delegate in cell For Item. You both have the same answer

Answer (score 2):

In your `SearchVideoController`, Have you assigned the delegate of your cell as like below?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchVideoCellID", for: indexPath) as! SearchVideoCell

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I forgot to assign my delegate in cell For Item. You both have the same answer

Comment: @ferryawijayanto but you can't accept(tick) both answers since there is no options ;)